# Trying to add a pageview controller without success....completely new at this

Tags: flutter, social-networking

I am completely new at coding and of course I am trying to tackle one of the largest projects I can think of.... anyways. I am running into a huge wall when it comes to my current stage of coding. I have a defaultTabController at the upper portion of the screen with the functionality to switch in between two tabs. I would also like to have a bottomNavigationBar at the bottom of the application with 5 buttons that navigate to additional pages.

I have been attempting to add this code `PageView(controller: _pageController, children: <Widget>[],)` to the body of my code, yet I am either getting an overload of errors or only the top or bottom nav bars are active. If someone could show me what I'm doing wrong, I would be so grateful!

```
    class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  int _currentTab = 0;
  PageController _pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          extendBody: true,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor:
            Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
              title: Text(
                'TREBLE',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                    fontFamily: "treblefont",
                    fontSize: (33.0)
          ),
          ),
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(text: "Following"),
                Tab(text: "trending"),
              ],
            )
          ),
          body:
          TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              FeedScreen(),
              TrendingScreen(),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
            currentIndex: _currentTab,
            onTap: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _currentTab = index;
              });
            },
            activeColor: Colors.black,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  size: 32.0,
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  size: 32.0,
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.camera_enhance,
                  size: 32.0,
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                  size: 32.0,
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.account_circle,
                  size: 32.0,
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I attempt to insert the code here:

```
        )
      ),
      body:
PageView(controller: _pageController, children: <Widget>[],)
      TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
          FeedScreen(),
          TrendingScreen(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        currentIndex: _currentTab,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentTab = index;
          });
        },
```

[line of code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/texyR.jpg)
[Specific error readout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQSu6.jpg)

Comment: where is the PageView implementation?

Comment: @ Omar Gamliel - I have tried to place the code right after the body section and it errors out. I have no clue where to add it or how to prevent it from throwing an error.

Comment: ok, what is the behavior you wish to achieve?

Comment: I would like to have each BottomNavigationBarItem navigate to their respective pages when pressed. Whenever I add the line of code to do so inside the body of the page, it cancels out the top bar.

Comment: can you upload a screenshot ?

Comment: I've added the screenshots to the original post